# When I do an android exception hook ,how to judge the assembler instruction is ARM or Thumb by address?

Tags: arm, hook, thumb

When I do an android exception hook ,how to judge the assembler instruction is ARM or Thumb by address ?   Doesn't the address of  thumb end with '0' ? 
when I switch ARM to thumb,I use "BX targetaddr+1",but the address of thumb still end with '0'.I don't know why.

```
void WriteillegalInstructionAndSaveOpcode(uint32_t addr, uint32_t    *OriginOpcode)
{
if(0x00000001 == (addr & 0x00000001))
{
    g_bIsThumb = 1;
    *OriginOpcode = *(uint32_t *)(addr & (~0x00000001));
    //Thumb illegal instruction : 0xdeXX
    uint32_t uiThumbillegalValue = 0x0000de00 | (0xFFFF0000 & *OriginOpcode);
    write_data_to_addr(addr & (~0x00000001), uiThumbillegalValue);
}
else
{
    g_bIsThumb = 0;
    //Arm illegal instruction: 0xf7fXaXXX
    *OriginOpcode = *(uint32_t *)addr;
    uint32_t uiArmillegalValue = 0x7f000f0;
    write_data_to_addr(addr, uiArmillegalValue);
}

LOGI("[+] g_bIsThumb is %08x \n",g_bIsThumb);
LOGI("[+] WriteillegalInstruction addr: %08x, OriginalOpcode is %08x",addr & (~0x00000001), *OriginOpcode);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

android so this is a full sized arm not a cortex-m.  Thumb instructions are 16 bits aligned on 16 bits, thumb2 are extensions, so a variable number (two) of 16 bit items.  So one lsbit of thumb is zero.  ARM instructions are 32 bits and have to be aligned so two lsbits have to be zero.  When the lsbit is set is for when you are doing a bx, blx, or pop (or the vector table in a cortex-m) the instruction/action consuming that address strips the lsbit going into the pc, the pc does not contain the lsbit being set (for thumb) the cpsr instead reflects this.  When the bl or blx happens the lr gets the pc plus two instructions and the lsbit is set if in thumb mode otherwise clear.

I think on full sized arms but you have to check the ARM ARM or ARM TRM for that core execute exceptions in ARM mode.

So for your question:

> Each exception mode also has a Saved Program Status Register (SPSR)
>   which holds the CPSR of the task immediately before the exception
>   occurred.

You should check the SPSR to check the T bit to see what mode you were in (assuming it was thumb or ARM), and then based on the exception examine what you need to examine to determine what address this bad instruction in this case was and then go read that item.  Being careful not to do a 32 bit read if it happens to be a thumb instruction not aligned on a 32 bit boundary.

Comment: If you get lucky and bit 1 of the address is set then it is a thumb instruction or since it is illegal it was in thumb mode.  If bit 1 is zero then you cant tell from the address.